# Reading a disk image without extension

Tags: windows, iso-image, file-extension, emulation, img

I have three files that are supposed to be disks image with a .img extension.
However, when I look at their properties, Windows says that it's just a file, without any extension. I tried to manually put .img at the end of the file's names, and thus turning them into supposed IMG files, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can open it ? I tried Daemon Tools and IMG to ISO converters, but nothing worked.

Comment: Were they originally supposed to have a .img extension? Disk images can come in different formats.

Comment: @DavidHoude Yes, they were. I've got another image coming from the same set of files with a .IMG extension, and they come from the same DVD making software.

Comment: Sounds like the files may be corrupted.

Comment: I believe the .img extension is overloaded, that is, there are multiple distinct formats using that same extension.  Do you know what the actual format of the files is, e.g., which program created them originally?

Comment: For example, might they actually be Macintosh disk image files?  That might explain the lack of an extension ...

Answer (score 1):

You might try 7-zip or another archive software. It could maybe manage to open it. If not, it could be interesting to see the first bytes of the file which can indicate which format it is.

They could as well be corrupted.

Comment: Tried 7-Zip and WinRAR, didn't work. I you want to see the first bytes, tell me how to get them. And I don't think they're corrupted because I actually saw their content displayed.

Comment: i guess these files are to large to share over the web. try to get head.exe (from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and do: `head yourfile > yourfile.head`. Then open it with a classic editor or an editor with hexadecimal view, and let us see what's the beginning. (i have no idea if it'll be helpful, but it's worth trying)

Comment: I downloaded head.exe, but when I type head [my file], it just prints head [my file]

Comment: it's strange, you should get something like this:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>head xcopy.exe
MZÉ ♥   ♦       ©       @                                   Ó   ♫▼║♫ ┤  ═!©☺L═!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
$       AÉ╣Õ♣±ÎÂ♣±ÎÂ♣±ÎÂã■ÏÂ♦±ÎÂ♣±ÍÂá±ÎÂã■è±ÎÂã■êÂ

Comment: nope, whenever I launch it I just have an empty console window.